# Kafka in microservices for providing transactions

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, event-driven

Can Kafka be used to provide transactions between microservices?

Let's say we build a simple online store with 2 microservices: order and storage.

While placing an order, you want to also update the quantity of a product in the storage. But when this action fails, you do not want to place an order. Also when the placing of the order fails, you want to rollback update of the storage.

Can this be easily achieved by using kafka? Would it be the best possible solution to provide consistency across microservices? And if so, should all communication between microservices be done using Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Kafka has transactions.

The producer can begin and end that transaction, but the consumer also needs to set its read isolation level to detect transaction markers.

https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kafka-transactions-and-guarantees/

There are other patterns to solve the same problem like Distributed Sagas and Outbox Pattern

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/01/patterns-for-distributed-transactions-within-a-microservices-architecture

https://www.infoq.com/articles/saga-orchestration-outbox/

Comment: Actually, I have a question to that answer. Can you please answer, if kafka would be useful exactly in this scenario: "While placing an order, you want to also update the quantity of a product in the storage. When this action fails, you do not want to place an order. Also when the placing of the order fails, you want to rollback update of the storage." Cause I believe orchestration is what I am looking for, but  my only second thought is - what if the storage service does not answer (for example it's down)? Would order service wait forever for this event? How to show this in the UI then?

Comment: Cause with synchronous communication it's pretty simple - if the server is down, you get immediate answer and you can print on UI that order has not been placed. What about this distributed transaction using Kafka? While clicking "place the order" and when the Kafka communication starts, should I show loader in the UI? If the order is placed successfully, you can show then the message about it, but if the storage service is down, how will we know that the order could not be placed? And what if the storage comes back to life - won't it consume the events that it missed?

Comment: I started to wonder if polling would be a solution to this. When user places an order, the server saves it to the database with status "QUEUED" and returns its location to the client, when the kafka communication is fine and transaction is successful, the status is being changed to "PLACED" and if the transaction fails (or message did not come to the queue in lets say 5 seconds - timeout) the status is changed to "FAILED". And then inform UI that in order to check the order status it should implement polling on their side, checking every 1sec the status of the order?

Comment: I suggest creating a new post for your specific question. But yes, I've used polling for eventually consistent data from Kafka before (which also happened to render in a UI}. However, websocket or SSE could be used as well, depending on data frequency